# Getting Device token in iphone6

Tags: iphone

Now I am upgrading my app from ios7 to ios8.
The pushnotificatin works on iphone5 but not iphone6.
Please answer who have experienced in this field.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've faced same problem and hope follow will help to you.
From ios sdk8, you can't use follow codes.

```html
[application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)];
```

Please try with this one.

```html
UIUserNotificationSettings *settings =
    [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert |
     UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
     UIUserNotificationTypeSound
                                      categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
```